# Http error after upgrading to .net core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

Our team upgrade our project from .net core rc2 to .net core 1.0.  When I run the integration test I get an error

> One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)) Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am not sure why it throws exception.

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc2-240",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",    
    "VisitorDigitalSignIn.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",
    "MimeKit": "1.4.2",
    "MailKit": "1.4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-10110",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Seq": "2.0.0-rc-46",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6",
        "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6",
        "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6",
        "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6",
        "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "netstandard1.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
        ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the project.json.

Comment: @rboe I post the project.json

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?